# Hover effect disappear after calling function through button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code which works only that not as I desire:

HTML:

```
  <div class="horizontal-ribbon">
    <div class="list" id="pseudoCheckBoxes">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="but" value="next" onclick="check()">
```

CSS:

```
.horizontal-ribbon {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    background: #d6dbdf;
}
.list {
    position:relative;
}
.list ul {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#d6dbdf;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-radius:0px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.list ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    padding:0px;
    background:#fff;
    border: 5px solid #d6dbdf;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    font: 700 13px"Lato", Helvetica, Arial sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-out, border-color 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-out, border-color 0.2s ease-out;
}
.list ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.list ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.list ul li:hover {
    background:#1abc9c;
    border-color:#1abc9c;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  function check() {
    element = document.getElementById("pseudoCheckBoxes");
    items = element.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    items[0].style.backgroundColor = "#1abc9c";
    items[0].style.borderColor = "#1abc9c";
    setTimeout(function () {
        uncheck()
    }, 2000);
}

function uncheck() {
    element = document.getElementById("pseudoCheckBoxes");
    items = element.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    items[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    items[0].style.borderColor = "#d6dbdf";
}
```

I wish to control that effect both from button press and by hovering the mouse of `<li>` elements.

The hover effect works well but after I click the button next the hover effect disappears and I don't know why. Please be kind and help me (http://jsfiddle.net/xfpyM/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying `:hover` effect using CSS hover and adding inline style after clicking the `next` button.

You can try doing it by adding class.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xfpyM/1/)

JS

```
function check(){
element=document.getElementById("pseudoCheckBoxes");
items=element.getElementsByTagName("LI");
items[0].className ="active";
setTimeout(function(){uncheck()}, 2000);
}
function uncheck(){
element=document.getElementById("pseudoCheckBoxes");
items=element.getElementsByTagName("LI");
items[0].className=" ";

}
```

CSS

```
.list ul li.active,
.list ul li:hover{
background:#1abc9c;
border-color:#1abc9c;
}
```

Comment: Yes, your code accomplish my desires; but to understand, by adding "items[0].className ="active";" i simulate the hover effect?

Comment: Yes, if that class has the same styling as the `:hover` selector

Answer (score 0):

Your `uncheck` function have some error. Instead of removing style attribute you are adding different styels. So the actual hover style not applying.

Instead of this

```
function uncheck() {
element = document.getElementById("pseudoCheckBoxes");
items = element.getElementsByTagName("LI");
items[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
items[0].style.borderColor = "#d6dbdf";
}
```

Use like this.

```
function uncheck() {
element = document.getElementById("pseudoCheckBoxes");
items = element.getElementsByTagName("LI");
items[0].removeAttribute("style");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xfpyM/2/)